# Problem in first claim of proof of theorem Every subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

With the start of the proof, the author JOSEPH A. GALLIAN first claim that every element of $H$ can be written in the form $a^n$ where $n$ is positive. For this: Since $G=[a]$, every element of $H$ has the form $a^t$; and when $a^t$ belongs to $H$ with $t<0$, then $a^{-t}$ belongs to $H$ also and $-t$ is positive. Thus, our claim is verified.

But now I have a doubt in the same.

Take 4th root of unity under multiplication and take $i^{-3}$ instead of $i$ as both of them are equal i.e.

$$ H =(\{i^{-3}, i^2, i^3,i^4\},\times )$$
Here in $i^2,i^2,i^4\to 2,3,4$ are positive so take it as it is. In $i^{-3} \to -3$ is negative take inverse of $i^{-3}$ i.e. $ i^3$. Now the obtained element so far is in some positive power of $i$ and belongs to $H$ (i.e. $\{i^3,i^2,i^3,i^4\}$ but are not forming group.

Am I wrong or the author means something else than this.[image]

Comment: You say, "the author" but you don't mention the text. Please share.

Comment: Joseph A GALLIAN

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT.

Comment: What you say the author claims is simply false. It is true in finite cyclic groups but not in infinite cyclic groups. That would be saying that the integer $-1$ is eqal to a positive integer, which is clearly nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the proof.

The author wants to claim that there exists **at least** one $a^t$ in the subgroup $H$ such that $t>0$. (Not that every element in $H$ is of the form $a^t$ where $t>0$.)

We may assume that $H$ is non-trivial subgroup.
Choose a non-identity element $x\in H$.
If $x=a^t$ where $t>0$, then we are done.
If $x=a^t$ where $t<0$, then note that $a^{-t}=x^{-1}\in H$. Since $-t>0$, so $x^{-1}$ is the desired element.

Comment: Hey what do you think of the group ({i^-¹,i^-²,i^-³,i^-⁴},×) with identity being i^-⁴ .

Comment: @JINENDRA it is still equal to the group $\{1,i,i^2,i^3\}$.

Comment: @JINENDRA The main point is there exists an $i^t$ inside the group such that $t>0$.

Comment: Ya it is equal but consider only that group.. even on taking inversed they will never get some positive power on them as we are considering only element of our group

Comment: @JINENDRA You just write the elements by using different representations but actually by using the order of $i$ the result still holds.

Comment: Actually you are not having my point . I wanna say that if ({1,w,w²},×)forms group but if we do w×w² then we get w³ but we dont write w³. Istead we write 1 which belong to group.  Following the same criteria if i choose (H={i^-¹,i^-²,i^-³,i^-⁴},×) then on taking inverse of any element say i^-³ then it is i³ but we write it i^-¹€H.Proceeding the same manner, we will never be going to have an element in its positive power. Hope you get what i want to say.

Comment: @JINENDRA No, fixing the way of writing an element is not the way to deal with group element. For example, $i^3$ can be also written as $i^7,i^{11}$ and so on.